# “Push” is to “pushable” as “enable”/"disable" are to what?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, analogy

If you can *push* something you could say it is *pushable*. What do you say about something which you can *enable* and about something which you can *disable*?

Comment: Wiktionary actually has [*disableable*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/disableable) (but not *enableable*, and there are no mentions of either in BNC/COCA).

Comment: Perhaps "supports enabling" and "supports disabling". There is no one-word word equivalent.

Comment: Something you can *disable* is *optional*, *toggleable*, or perhaps *switchable*.

Comment: You could say *pushable*.  It's not a word in the dictionary but if that's ok, why not *enableable*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Capable of being enabled* and *capable of being disabled*, and for something which you can troll, you can say *capable of being trolled*.

Comment: Yep! I wish there were a more succinct way to say this, but @mgkrebbs has come up with the best solution that I can think of.

Comment: I agree @mgkrebbs gave a solid answer. But I would add 'incapable' as the mate of 'disable'.

Answer (score 3):

Going way back to one of the earliest machine parts designs, you have the [toggle switch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toggle_switch#Toggle_switch), which gives rise nicely to the intransitive verb usage of [**toggle**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/toggle)

> To alternate between two or more electronic, mechanical, or computer-related options, usually by the operation of a single switch or keystroke: *toggled back and forth between two windows on the screen.*

This has a past-tense **toggled** and a present tense **toggleing** and apparently an adjective form [**togglable**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/togglable#English) or [**toggleable**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/toggleable)

> **1.** Able to be toggled.
>
> *That button is **togglable**.*

(And no, I did not add that to Wiktionary just now.)

A toggle is generally recognized as being a binary condition, one or the other. I think it is a nice fit for *capable of being enabled and disabled*.

You could also use [**switchable**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/switchable), but it does not have as strong of a connotation for binary states and would cause more confusion.

Comment: `toggle` carries the implication that upon activation the thing will change to the *other* state, whichever state it is currently in. To enable something is to put it in an active state, regardless of whether it is currently active already or not, and similarly for disable.