# Something that can be activated/enabled

Tags: single-word-requests

What adjective can you use to say that something can be activated or enabled? (Something akin to "active-able" or ["enable-able"](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=enableable), which are not recognized words.)

"You can activate this product" -> "This is a _______ product"

"Given a _______ product, you can press this button"

NOTE: togglable is not a valid response, because togglable implies the change is two-ways, and I want it to be one-way (inactive -> active)

Comment: What if you said "Activate this product". Then you'd say "Activate a product to press (click?) this button".

Comment: If it's only one way, does that mean the product (whatever it is) can never be disabled once enabled?

Comment: See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22372/push-is-to-pushable-as-enable-disable-are-to-what

Comment: Enable-ready.  Example: This is an enable-ready product.  Just press this button to enable.

Answer (score 13):

It might sound a bit weird, but *activable*

> : capable of being activated

(source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/activable))

fits the bill.

Wiktionary lists [*activatable*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/activatable) which is a more regular way to decline 'to activate', but more reputable dictionaries don't list it. Still, I think it will be understood too.

Comment: *Activable* sounds weird to me too (what, it can be \*actived?). But -able is productive, so *activatable* works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Something that can be *turned on*, *run* or *used* is said to be

> [**operable**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/topics/technology/functioning/) *adjective* (working)
> able to be used:
>
> *There will be a delay before the modified machines are operable.*

Cambridge Dictionary

Comment: I'd argue in this case, it's not operable until it's turned on. But maybe I've been using "operable" wrong my whole life!

Comment: @only_pro: I'd say it's *operable* if it *could* be operated, even if it's not turned on yet, and *operating* when it's on.

Comment: @Anonymous I agree, but I suppose from my perspective, it *can't* be operated *until* it's turned on. To me, turning on is not part of operation. English is funny.

Answer (score 3):

<sup>Didn't read the question carefully enough earlier...</sup>

Consider ***startable***:

> 1. That can be started.
>      <sub>[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/startable)</sub>

Seems to work well in your context:

> *Given a **startable** product, you can press this button.*

Answer (score 2):

**[Inducible](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inducible)** relates to something capable of activation, especially on a molecular level.

> : **capable of being induced**: such as
>
> a : formed by a cell in response to the presence of its substrate (inducible enzymes)
>
> b : **activated** or undergoing expression only in the presence of a particular molecule (an inducible promoter)

...

> : **capable of being formed, activated, or expressed in response to a stimulus** especially of a molecular kind:

Comment: This is specific to biology, though; it doesn't work for the *product* in the question.

Answer (score 2):

[Latent](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/latent) (*adjective*) might work.

> Present or potential but not evident or active.

I think this matches at least part of the question, since the notions of "enable-able" and "currently inactive" are inherent here.

I'm not sure it's correct for the context of describing a product, but I like the word enough to toss it into the ring.